# Create new table from query results is slow in Python with SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

Using Python, I try to create a new SQLite table in a database from a query result which is executed on two other tables in that database.

For the record, the query is

```
CREATE TABLE results AS

    SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
    FROM table_1
        LEFT JOIN table_2
            ON table_1.ID_1 = table_2.ID_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
    FROM table_2
        LEFT JOIN table_1
            ON table_1.ID_1 = table_2.ID_2
    WHERE table_1.ID_1 IS NULL
```

which is supposed to be a workaround for a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which is not directly available in SQLite (this method can be found on different SO threads on this topic).

However, this operation is slow on my tables with ~1 million rows each... so slow that I get the impression it's going to take hours when hitting refresh in the Explorer Window showing the database's file size while updating.

How can I get this faster? I already did a lot of research on this and most of the time, people are talking about using transactions because otherwise, each row will open up a new connection to the database or whatever... however, I could not find a working example on how to use this.

My two approaches so far which are way too slow:

Using Python's `sqlite3` module:

```
# open sqlite database
conn = sqlite3.connect('Database.sqlite')

# get a cursor
cursor = conn.cursor()

# start query
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE results AS
    SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
    FROM table_1
        LEFT JOIN table_2
            ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
    FROM table_2
        LEFT JOIN table_1
            ON table_1.ID = table_2.NETWORK_ID
    WHERE table_1.ID IS NULL
;""")
```

Using [sqalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite

# create database engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///Database.sqlite')

# open sqlite database
connection = engine.connect()

# query
with connection.begin() as trans:
    connection.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION;")

    connection.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE results AS

        SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
        FROM table_1
            LEFT JOIN table_2
                ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT table_1.*, table_2.*
        FROM table_2
            LEFT JOIN table_1
                ON table_1.ID = table_2.ID
        WHERE table_1.ID IS NULL
    ;""")

    trans.commit()
```

Comment: _"people are talking about using transactions because otherwise, each row will open up a new connection to the database or whatever"_ Could you provide a pointer to such statement ? Sounds kind of crazy to me. And AFAIK, there is no point in wrapping _one_ select statement in a transaction ? Or is it ? SQLite might sometime be surprising...

Comment: ... I forgot to ask: do you have index on your join columns ?

Comment: Uhm, maybe I misread the other posts and they were about doing something different, will check on this later. However, yep, I created an index on the join columns (hopefully right). I should have added that only printing the JOIN result without writing to a new table takes like 5-10 seconds so this does not seem to be the bottleneck here.

Answer (score 1):

Argh... the problem was not with the code above but with the tables that provide the input for the JOIN. I lacked some accuracy while creating them so that `ID` column of `table_1` was of type `INTEGER` while `ID` column of `table_2` was of type `STRING`.

Unfortunately, doing a JOIN on columns of different types does not throw an error - instead I guess that something very expensive is happening internally like casting each `STRING` to `INTEGER`, comparing and then casting back to `STRING` or vice versa.

So, the moral of the story: If your `CREATE TABLE` from a `JOIN` is painfully slow then check the data types of your `JOIN` columns for equality.